# Add select object dynamically to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to generate two drop-down lists( element) and append them to a table as new row.

These two lists are created by reading an already existing select element.

```
var sfp_opt = document.getElementById('sfp_opt');
var sfps = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sfp_opt.children.length; ++i) {
    var child = sfp_opt.children[i];
    if (child.tagName == 'OPTION') sfps.push(child.value);
}
counter += 1;
var s1 = $("<select></select>");
s1.id = 'SfpSelId' + counter;
s1.name = 'SfpSelName' + counter;

for(var val in sfps) {
    $("<option />", {value: val, text: sfps[val]}).appendTo(s1);
}
```

Similarly I am creating one more select element called s2.
I want to append these two lists in separate `<td>` but same row i.e `<tr>`.
So I tried these methods:

1)
`$("#sfp_det tbody").append('<tr><td>'+s1+'</td><td>'+s2+'</td></tr>');`

And being incorrect this appear as [object Object] on UI.s1.val() also doesn't help.

2) I can use .wrap() function. This works for one list.

```
$("#sfp_det tbody").append($(s1).wrap('<tr><td></td></tr>'));
```

My question is how do I append two lists similarly so that I get it in a format equivalent to `<table><tr><td>list1(s1)</td><td>list2(s2)</td></tr></table>` where s1 and s2 are drop down lists or select elements? Is it possible to do it using .wrap()?
If not, can anyone please suggest me the correct syntax to get this done?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can use wrapAll.

Comment: How do i use it? I have tried this and it doesn't work:    `$(s1).wrap('<td class="a1"/>');$(s2).wrap('<td class="a1"/>');  $("#sfp_det tbody").append($('.a1').wrapAll('<tr></tr>'));`Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I updated my answer (js link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
    var select1 = $('<select>');
    var select2 = $('<select>');

    wrapWithTd(select1).add(wrapWithTd(select2)).wrapAll('<tr>');        

    $('table tbody').append(select1.parents('tr'));

    function wrapWithTd(el) {
        el.wrap('<td>');
        return el.parent();
    }
```

See at:
http://jsfiddle.net/inser/c36VT/